# Why is google drive not working?

Tags: google-drive, windows-7

Google drive is not working. When installing I get this error message which says the error code is `8bd0` if that helps.

[image]

It used to work but now after a power cycle it doesn't. What am I doing wrong? The shortcut to google drive does not appear on the desktop and I'm not logged into google drive. It is wrong.

### Update

This is the log from running it in diagnostic mode. I already tried reinstall completely and the problem is still there.

```
2013-05-01 13:01:10,571 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      logging:1600 OS: Windows/6.1.7601-SP1
2013-05-01 13:01:10,572 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      logging:1600 Google Drive (build 1.9.4536.8202)
2013-05-01 13:01:10,572 DEBUG pid=1088 9040:MainThread      logging:1608 DEBUGGING DUMP is ON.
2013-05-01 13:01:10,589 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      resources.images.image_resources:136 Loading image resources\images\win7-inactive.png
2013-05-01 13:01:10,605 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      resources.images.image_resources:136 Loading image resources\images\menu_warning.png
2013-05-01 13:01:10,608 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      logging:1600 Setting Omaha usage flag in registry
2013-05-01 13:01:10,631 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      resources.images.image_resources:136 Loading image resources\images\sync.png
2013-05-01 13:01:10,654 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:244 Open master connection to C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,655 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:244 Open master connection to C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,657 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        logging:1600 ADDING persistence_sqlite:514c7130116a4d87be61e81b8cd6a53dC:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,657 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        logging:1600 ADDING persistence_sqlite:f392b3a3055d4e64ba81b2b73e9b1344C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,694 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:349 Close connection. path=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,696 DEBUG pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,696 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:349 Close connection. path=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,697 DEBUG pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,700 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        logging:1600 Execute cleanup callback 'persistence_sqlite:f392b3a3055d4e64ba81b2b73e9b1344C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db'
2013-05-01 13:01:10,700 DEBUG pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,700 INFO pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        logging:1600 Execute cleanup callback 'persistence_sqlite:514c7130116a4d87be61e81b8cd6a53dC:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db'
2013-05-01 13:01:10,700 DEBUG pid=1088 7232:Thread-1        common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,703 DEBUG pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   logging:1608 thread LaunchThreads starting
2013-05-01 13:01:10,703 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:244 Open master connection to C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,704 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:244 Open master connection to C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,706 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   logging:1600 ADDING persistence_sqlite:3c8f392c029a41ba97759f1dbf5e57f1C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,707 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   logging:1600 ADDING persistence_sqlite:32684d76588743e7987ab1521830a5f6C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,707 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   logging:1600 Execute cleanup callback 'persistence_sqlite:32684d76588743e7987ab1521830a5f6C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db'
2013-05-01 13:01:10,707 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:349 Close connection. path=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_config.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,709 DEBUG pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,709 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   logging:1600 Execute cleanup callback 'persistence_sqlite:3c8f392c029a41ba97759f1dbf5e57f1C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db'
2013-05-01 13:01:10,709 INFO pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:349 Close connection. path=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\snapshot.db
2013-05-01 13:01:10,710 DEBUG pid=1088 8460:LaunchThreads   common.persistence_sqlite:53 
#####################################
SQLite open connections:
set([])
#####################################
2013-05-01 13:01:10,819 INFO pid=1088 9040:MainThread      resources.images.image_resources:136 Loading image resources\images\win7-error.png
```

Comment: You can start Google Drive in diagnostic mode by running `googledrivesync.exe --vv`. It will then generate a log file at `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\sync_log.log`. See if that gets you more information.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Thank you for the comment, I ran the diagnostics and updated the questions with my findings from there. Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything in that log that looks out of the ordinary :( I have only found [one report](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/N27r_2H0ZDc) of this issue. Maybe it's something specific to your user profile. You could try to run Google Drive in a new user profile, just to see if it is a system-wide problem. Possibly, not all files are removed when uninstalling and reinstalling Drive. Maybe Drive can't write to a certain file :\

Comment: @OliverSalzburg It works now that I switched Windows user accounts. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was what caused and fixed the problem for me:

My windows 7 User account was set to not have a password (so i can boot straight to desktop without having to enter credentials). In this configuration neither google drive or drop box would work. I set a password on the account, both work fine now.

HTH

Tom

Comment: It works now that I switched Windows user accounts. Thanks for the help.